# Are "other than" and "different than" the same?

Tags: meaning, comparative-constructions

> Rainbows can be other than they seem, and seem other than they are.

From "Understanding Music: Philosophy and Interpretation" by Roger Scruton.

I am not sure if it's the case, but "other than" seem to be the same as "different than". I think it sounds odd however, and I am not sure if it's idiomatic. Is it?

Comment: Strictly, it's 'different **from**', but many people accept 'different than' for informal use.

Comment: Is other than informal?

Comment: "Other than" is not informal. It's standard usage.

Comment: Other than; different from. Different than is common in American English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Other than*** has one common usage to indicate exceptions:

> There's nothing to eat, **other than** ramen.

And a less common but generally recognised usage that seems closer to *different*:

> Don't try to be other than you are.

Really, at root they are the same meaning. However, they way they are used *feels* different. Generally speaking, the two verbs in the second usage - *be* and *seem* in your examples, or two lots of *be* in mine - should be linking verbs, and it just suggests the possibility of being, seeming, looking (etc) different things.

It is perfectly idiomatic, though it has a sense of feeling like an older, more formal, or more artsy usage.